# Linq query to display the values from two tables even if one of the table doesn't have any corresponding record

Tags: c#, join, entity-framework-6

I'm working on a project where we have two tables `People` and `Emails`. I wanted to display the `People` records with his `Emails` whether `Emails` table have the person's emails or not.

I tried with the below query but it displays the record only when the Person's Email rocord is available in table.

```
_db.People.Join(_db.Emails, e => e.PersonId, p=> p.PersonId, (e, p) => new { e, p }).Where(x => x.p.PersonId == personId).Select(x => new { Id = x.p.PersonId, x.p.FirstName, x.p.LastName, x.p.Gender, x.e.EmailAddress})OrderBy(x => x.Id).ToList();
```

Can anyone suggest how would I display all People which have or doesn't have the EmailAddress in `Emails` table.

Thank You!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Blinq%5Dleft+outer+join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want a Left Join using Linq:

```
var results = (from p in _db.People
               join e in _db.Emails
               on p.PersonId equals e.PersonId into LeftJoin
               from res in LeftJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
               select new
               {
                  Id = p.PersonId, 
                  FirstName = p.FirstName, 
                  LastName = p.LastName, 
                  Gender = p.Gender, 
                  Email = res == null ? null : res.EmailAddress
               }).ToList();
```

Hope this works fine.